# Ionic Angular http get not firing after successful barcode scan using async and await

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, barcode-scanner

I'm having trouble running an HttpClient GET function after a successful scan of a barcode. The barcode scanning is working but when I pass the barcode value to my get function nothing happens. I'm using async and await but must be missing something.

My HTTP GET function:

```
getOrderFromShopify(requestUrl: any) {
  
  this.http.get(requestUrl)
    .subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      this.order_details = data["order"];
      this.line_items = data["order"]["line_items"];
    })
}
```

My Barcode Scan function:

```
async scanCode() {
    this.barcodeScanner
      .scan()
      .then(async barcodeData => {

        const baseURL = 'https://xxxxxxx.xxx?';
        const queryOptions = 'order_name=' + barcodeData.text; //Keep going
        let requestUrl = `${baseURL}${queryOptions}`;

        await this.getOrderFromShopify(requestUrl);

        this.scannedData = barcodeData;
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log("Error", err);
      });
  }
```

Comment: is this.getURL supposed to be this.getOrderFromShopify ?

Comment: Mike, yes you're right. My appologies. I have several variations for the scanning and get functions as I was testing variations between the async and await uses. I've updated my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to the community! I saw in your function that you are using `async` statement. It is not on the documentation of [Ionic barcode](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/barcode-scanner). Try to remove it, also on the callback function. In case you are not getting the barcode results, try to convert it to Integer like `parseInt(barcodeData);`

```
 scanCode() {
    this.barcodeScanner.scan()
      .then(barcodeData => {
        const queryOptions = 'order_name=' + barcodeData.text;
        let requestUrl = `${baseURL}${queryOptions}`;
        await this.getOrderFromShopify(requestUrl);
        this.scannedData = barcodeData;
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log("Error", err);
      });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, I gave that a shot but I get "Cannot find name 'barcodeData'". Also, if I take the async out of the then statement the await this.getOrderFromShopify(requestUrl) gives me "'await' expression is only allowed within an async function"

Comment: I updated the answer to "It is not on the documentation of Ionic barcode. In case you are not getting the barcode resulta, try to convert it to Integer like parseInt(barcodeData);" Hope it helps you!

Comment: The function this.getOrderFromShopify(requestUrl)  doesn’t return a Promise so await has no use there anyway..